# Populate Nest Field In Mongoose Express Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**i am creating report functionality for my app. below is the post schema for the report **

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    reported_post: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      refPath: "post_type",
      required: true,
    },
    post_type: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        "lost_found",
        "sell",
        "neighbour-watch",
        "skill",
        "neighbour-forum",
      ],
      required: true,
    },
    reports: [
      { email: String, reason: String, date: String, optional_note: String },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export const Report = mongoose.model("report", reportSchema);
```

**when i try to get all reports and populate the reported_post its just work fine but there is a nest field posted_by which is also ref to user when i try to populate it it does not work**

```
export const getPostReports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const reports = await Report.find()
      .populate("reported_post")
      .populate("reported_post.posted_by")
      .sort({ updatedAt: -1 });

    res.status(200).json(reports);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

**Api Response :**
[image: postman api response]

Also tried -> .populate({ path: "reported_post.posted_by", model: "user" })
it still shows posted_by just an id i want to populate posted_by too

Comment: Could you try to populate them in one populate as; .populate({ path: "reported_post", populate: { path: 'posted_by' }}). You can add model as well if it doesn't work for you; .populate({ path: "reported_post", populate: { path: 'posted_by', model: "user" }})

Comment: It works Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!